# How to evaluate binary key-value?

Tags: scala, sorting

I am writing a external merge sort for big input files in Binary using Scala. 
I generate input using gensort and evaluate output using valsort from this website: http://www.ordinal.com/gensort.html

I will read 100 bytes at a time, first 10 bytes for `Key(List[Byte])` and the rest 90 bytes for `Value(List[Byte])`
After sorting, my output is evaluated by valsort, and it's wrong.

But when I using input in ASCII, my output is right.

So I wonder how to sort binary inputs in the right way?

Valsort said that my first unordered record is 56, here is what I printed out:

```
50 --> Key(List(-128, -16, 5, -10, -83, 23, -107, -109, 42, -11))
51 --> Key(List(-128, -16, 5, -10, -83, 23, -107, -109, 42, -11))
52 --> Key(List(-128, -10, -10, 68, -94, 37, -103, 30, 90, 16))
53 --> Key(List(-128, -10, -10, 68, -94, 37, -103, 30, 90, 16))
54 --> Key(List(-128, -10, -10, 68, -94, 37, -103, 30, 90, 16))
55 --> Key(List(-128, -10, -10, 68, -94, 37, -103, 30, 90, 16))
56 --> Key(List(-128, 0, -27, -4, -82, -82, 121, -125, -22, 99))
57 --> Key(List(-128, 0, -27, -4, -82, -82, 121, -125, -22, 99))
58 --> Key(List(-128, 0, -27, -4, -82, -82, 121, -125, -22, 99))
59 --> Key(List(-128, 0, -27, -4, -82, -82, 121, -125, -22, 99))
60 --> Key(List(-128, 7, -65, 118, 121, -12, 48, 50, 59, -8))
61 --> Key(List(-128, 7, -65, 118, 121, -12, 48, 50, 59, -8))
62 --> Key(List(-128, 7, -65, 118, 121, -12, 48, 50, 59, -8))
```

This is my external sorting code:

```
package externalsorting

import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, File, FileOutputStream}
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel
import java.util.Calendar

import scala.collection.mutable
import readInput._

import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
/**
  * Created by hminle on 12/5/2016.
  */
object ExternalSortingExample extends App{
  val dir: String = "C:\\ShareUbuntu\\testMerge"
  val listFile: List[File] = Utils.getListOfFiles(dir)
  listFile foreach(x => println(x.getName))
  var fileChannelsInput: List[(FileChannel, Boolean)] = listFile.map{input => (Utils.getFileChannelFromInput(input), false)}
  val tempDir: String = dir + "/tmp/"
  val tempDirFile: File = new File(tempDir)
  val isSuccessful: Boolean = tempDirFile.mkdir()
  if(isSuccessful) println("Create temp dir successfully")
  else println("Create temp dir failed")

  var fileNameCounter: Int = 0
  val chunkSize = 100000
  // Split big input files into small chunks
  while(!fileChannelsInput.isEmpty){
    if(Utils.estimateAvailableMemory() > 400000){
      val fileChannel = fileChannelsInput(0)._1
      val (chunks, isEndOfFileChannel) = Utils.getChunkKeyAndValueBySize(chunkSize, fileChannel)
      if(isEndOfFileChannel){
        fileChannel.close()
        fileChannelsInput = fileChannelsInput.drop(1)
      } else {
        val sortedChunk: List[(Key, Value)] = Utils.getSortedChunk(chunks)
        val fileName: String = tempDir + "partition-" + fileNameCounter
        Utils.writePartition(fileName, sortedChunk)
        fileNameCounter += 1
      }
    } else {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName +"There is not enough available free memory to continue processing" + Utils.estimateAvailableMemory())
    }
  }


  val listTempFile: List[File] = Utils.getListOfFiles(tempDir)
  val start = Calendar.getInstance().getTime

  val tempFileChannels: List[FileChannel] = listTempFile.map(Utils.getFileChannelFromInput(_))
  val binaryFileBuffers: List[BinaryFileBuffer] = tempFileChannels.map(BinaryFileBuffer(_))
  binaryFileBuffers foreach(x => println(x.toString))

  val pq1: ListBuffer[BinaryFileBuffer] = ListBuffer.empty
  binaryFileBuffers.filter(!_.isEmpty()).foreach(pq1.append(_))
  val outputDir: String = dir + "/mergedOutput"
  val bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputDir))

  // Start merging temporary files
  while(pq1.length > 0){
    val pq2 = pq1.toList.sortWith(_.head()._1 < _.head()._1)
    val buffer: BinaryFileBuffer = pq2.head
    val keyVal: (Key, Value) = buffer.pop()

    val byteArray: Array[Byte] = Utils.flattenKeyValue(keyVal).toArray[Byte]
    Stream.continually(bos.write(byteArray))
    if(buffer.isEmpty()){
      buffer.close()
      pq1 -= buffer
    }
    count+=1
  }
  bos.close()

}
```

This is BinaryFileBuffer.scala --> which is just a wrapper

```
package externalsorting

import java.nio.channels.FileChannel
import readInput._
/**
  * Created by hminle on 12/5/2016.
  */
object BinaryFileBuffer{
  def apply(fileChannel: FileChannel): BinaryFileBuffer = {
    val buffer: BinaryFileBuffer = new BinaryFileBuffer(fileChannel)
    buffer.reload()
    buffer
  }
}
class BinaryFileBuffer(fileChannel: FileChannel) extends Ordered[BinaryFileBuffer] {
  private var cache: Option[(Key, Value)] = _

  def isEmpty(): Boolean = cache == None
  def head(): (Key, Value) = cache.get
  def pop(): (Key, Value) = {
    val answer = head()
    reload()
    answer
  }
  def reload(): Unit = {
    this.cache = Utils.get100BytesKeyAndValue(fileChannel)
  }
  def close(): Unit = fileChannel.close()

  def compare(that: BinaryFileBuffer): Int = {
    this.head()._1.compare(that.head()._1)
  }
}
```

This is my Utils.scala:

```
package externalsorting

import java.io.{BufferedOutputStream, File, FileOutputStream}
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel
import java.nio.file.Paths

import readInput._

import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
/**
  * Created by hminle on 12/5/2016.
  */
object Utils {
  def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[File] = {
    val d = new File(dir)
    if(d.exists() && d.isDirectory){
      d.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
    } else  List[File]()
  }
  def get100BytesKeyAndValue(fileChannel: FileChannel): Option[(Key, Value)] = {
    val size = 100
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
    buffer.clear()
    val numOfByteRead = fileChannel.read(buffer)
    buffer.flip()
    if(numOfByteRead != -1){
      val data: Array[Byte] = new Array[Byte](numOfByteRead)
      buffer.get(data, 0, numOfByteRead)
      val (key, value) = data.splitAt(10)
      Some(Key(key.toList), Value(value.toList))
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
  def getFileChannelFromInput(file: File): FileChannel = {
    val fileChannel: FileChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(file.getPath))
    fileChannel
  }

  def estimateAvailableMemory(): Long = {
    System.gc()
    val runtime: Runtime = Runtime.getRuntime
    val allocatedMemory: Long = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()
    val presFreeMemory: Long = runtime.maxMemory() - allocatedMemory
    presFreeMemory
  }
  def writePartition(dir: String, keyValue: List[(Key, Value)]): Unit = {
    val byteArray: Array[Byte] = flattenKeyValueList(keyValue).toArray[Byte]
    val bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dir))
    Stream.continually(bos.write(byteArray))
    bos.close()
  }

  def flattenKeyValueList(keyValue: List[(Key,Value)]): List[Byte] = {
    keyValue flatten {
      case (Key(keys), Value(values)) => keys:::values
    }
  }

  def flattenKeyValue(keyVal: (Key, Value)): List[Byte] = {
    keyVal._1.keys:::keyVal._2.values
  }
  def getChunkKeyAndValueBySize(size: Int, fileChannel: FileChannel): (List[(Key, Value)], Boolean) = {
    val oneKeyValueSize = 100
    val countMax = size / oneKeyValueSize
    var isEndOfFileChannel: Boolean = false
    var count = 0
    val chunks: ListBuffer[(Key, Value)] = ListBuffer.empty
    do{
      val keyValue = get100BytesKeyAndValue(fileChannel)
      if(keyValue.isDefined) chunks.append(keyValue.get)
      isEndOfFileChannel = !keyValue.isDefined
      count += 1
    }while(!isEndOfFileChannel && count < countMax)
    (chunks.toList, isEndOfFileChannel)
  }
  def getSortedChunk(oneChunk: List[(Key, Value)]): List[(Key, Value)] = {
    oneChunk.sortWith((_._1 < _._1))
  }
}
```

How I define Key and Value:

```
case class Key(keys: List[Byte]) extends Ordered[Key] {
  def isEmpty(): Boolean = keys.isEmpty
  def compare(that: Key): Int = {
    compare_aux(this.keys, that.keys)
  }
  private def compare_aux(keys1: List[Byte], keys2: List[Byte]): Int = {
    (keys1, keys2) match {
      case (Nil, Nil) => 0
      case (list, Nil) => 1
      case (Nil, list) => -1
      case (hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2) => {
        if(hd1 > hd2) 1
        else if(hd1 < hd2) -1
        else compare_aux(tl1, tl2)
      }
    }
  }
}
case class Value(values: List[Byte])
```

Comment: You are either reading it wrong, writing it wrong, or sorting it wrong. 
Not sure how you expect anyone to be able to tell more without seeing the actual code ...

Comment: @Dima: Hi, sorry about that, I've updated my post.

Comment: Tried to debug it yet? Any luck? Break it into smaller functions, perhaps? Test them separately. Write some unit tests to make sure they do what you intended them to.

Comment: My code runs correctly with ASCII inputs, but wrong with Binary ones. And I try to print it out like above but see nothing strange, the Key are listed in right order. Why valsort tells it wrong? That's what I wonder

Comment: @Dima so is sorting binary file different with sorting ASCII file?

Comment: Evidently so, if what you are saying is correct, and it sorts ascii correctly, but not binary ...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. Reading from Binary and ASCII are different.

```
In what order should the sorted file be?
For binary records (GraySort or MinuteSort), the 10-byte keys should be ordered as arrays of unsigned bytes. The memcmp() library routine can be used for this purpose.
```

For sorting Binary, I need to convert signed bytes into unsigned bytes.